# update manager does not update

Tags: update-manager

Good afternoon everyone;

I am trying to update my system using update manager. However, I face with this error message;

```
Preconfiguring packages ...

Setting up util-linux (2.20.1-1ubuntu3.1) ...

update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme': Not a directory

dpkg: error processing util-linux (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:

 util-linux

Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.8.2-2ubuntu31.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme': Not a directory

dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up util-linux (2.20.1-1ubuntu3.1) ...

update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme': 

Not a directory
dpkg: error processing util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

I searched this problem over the internet and I tried these commands;

```
sudo apt-get upgrade install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

However, none of them seems to be working. Could you help me please ? (I use elementary os)

Comment: When you paste in code, please select it and press Ctrl+K, it formats it so we can tell what is code and what is your text easier. You can also use the `\`` character (accent, below the Esc key) at the beginning of code, so `\`hello\`` will look like code in comments and the question/answer box.

Comment: Apologize for the inconvenience Tim.I will be mindful about this for the next time for sure.

Comment: It's fine, thanks for using Ask ubuntu, and I hope we find a solution for your problem!

Comment: I realize something. I can't install any package at the moment. Because it seems there is something wrong with util-linux.However, I don't know what is the problem. I saw quite a lot of people tackle with this problem.

Comment: Could you post `update-alternatives --display x-cursor-theme` output?

Comment: Dear Letizia; Apologise for late reply. I updated my kernel in elementary os and I believe my problem occured because of this reason.So I switched back to ubuntu from elementary os. I don't have any problem at the moment.Thanks for your help.